# Access to XMLHttpRequest at my api from origin has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, cors, xmlhttprequest, asp.net-core-2.0

I get the following error when I'm calling my API method from the client app. I am using .NET Core v2.1.6 and .NET SDK v2.1.502 and my client app is using Angular v5.2.0

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login'
> from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
> Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

Here's a picture of this error:[image]

I tried a different approach by using a custom cors policy in startup.cs. I can fetch data from API using postman easily but from the client app, it is not happening.

My Startup.cs functions:

```cs
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                       .AllowCredentials();
            }));
            services.AddScoped<IAuthRepository, AuthRepository>();
            services.AddSignalR();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            //app.UseCors(x => x.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200/").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowCredentials());
            app.UseMvc();
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
            
        }
```

Using this service from my client app to validate the input data:

```cs
export class AuthService {
    baseUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/api/auth/';
    userToken: any;
    //
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    login(model: any) {
        const headers = new Headers({ 'content-type': 'application/json' });
        const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'login', model, options).map((response: Response) => {
            const user = response.json();
            if (user) {
                localStorage.setItem('token', user.tokenString);
            }
                this.userToken = user.tokenString;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: From this post i can assume that this is happening because i use 'Content-Type' 'Application/json'. What should i use then. Or if i use it, what should i need to do?

Comment: Use the Network pane in browser devtools to inspect the response to the OPTIONS preflight request. Check the `Location` header, and see what URL it’s trying to redirect the request to. Then change the URL in your frontend JavaScript code to fit the value of that `Location` header. It could be something as simple as a trailing slash in the URL — for example, you may need to change the URL to  `http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login/` (notice the trailing slash) rather than the `http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login` (no trailing slash) URL your code is currently sending the request to.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to access an endpoint in different domain / port, you should [configure a proxy](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md) for your angular application. For example:

1. Create a file in your project root folder, `proxy.conf.json`.
2. Example content:

   ```
   {
     "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:3000",
      "secure": false
    }
   }
   ```
3. In your angular.json file, add the proxy file configuration:

   ```
   "architect": {
     "serve": {
       "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
       "options": {
         "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
         "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
       },
   ```
4. If you Angular version is 5 or lower, there is no angular.json file, and you can still refer to the proxy as a cli parameter, for example:

   ```
   "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.js"
   ```

Comment: Couldn't add the third option in my angular.json(.angular-cli.json) file. It shows property 'architect' is not allowed. Please help.

Comment: Then you must be using an older angular version, you can still refer to the proxy using by changing your start command in `package.json`: `"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.js"`

Comment: I am using angular cli v1.6.6 angular v5.2.0